# Hide related lists on Contact depending on a picklist value

Tags: page-layout, contact

I have a picklist field on Contact 'Group' with values A and B. My requirement is if select 'A' , all the related lists of Contacts should be visible but if I select 'B', all the related lists (the lookups) should hid on standard page layout of Contact. Is there a workaround for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to show different Standard page Layouts is to use **different record types** and based on the picklist value selected while saving a record **use a workflow rule + field update** to **change the record type** of the record which can then display the **associated page layout**..